# Find Limit of the given function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\ln(1-x)\cot\left({{\pi x}\over2}\right)$$

Comment: What have you tried, what kind of limit do you recognise? And first of all, this limit does not exist over the reals because $\ln(1-x)$ then isn't defined for $x>1$.

Comment: do you mean when $x\to 1$ from the left or did you mean $\ln(|1-x|)$??

Comment: @barto yes i understand that. but this is what the question is :) I tried expanding ln in its taylor expansion and taking limit. didn't work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $1-x=y$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}} \ln(1-x)cot({{\pi x}\over2})$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0^+}\ln y\tan \frac {\pi y}2$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\ln y}{\cot \frac {\pi y}2}\text{ which is of the form }\frac \infty \infty$$

So, applying L'Hospital's Rule,

$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\ln y}{\cot \frac {\pi y}2}=\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1}{-y\csc^2 \frac {\pi y}2\frac\pi2}$$

$$=-\frac\pi2 \left(\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\sin \frac {\pi y}2}{\frac {\pi y}2}\right)^2\cdot \lim_{y\to0^+}y=0$$

Comment: Nice !! thanks..

Comment: @AmanMittal, my pleasure